# How do I inject $cookies into an AngularJS service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, cookies, dependency-injection

I read the documentation for `$cookies`  [at this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies), and it suggests using the following syntax to inject `$cookies`:

```
angular.module('cookiesExample', ['ngCookies'])
   .controller('ExampleController', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
```

I therefore tried the following syntax to inject `$cookies` into a service (note `factory` instead of `controller` below:

```
angular.module('auth', ['ngCookies'])
     .factory( 'auth', '$cookies',  function($rootScope, $http, $location, $cookies) {
```

But the result is an obscure compilation error in FireFox that keeps the app from compiling.  The error is many tens of thousands of characters into `angular-bootstrap.js` and is unreachable because `angular-bootstrap.js` is compressed into perhaps 20 lines of 10,000+ characters per line.  Since `angular-bootstrap.js` has not been modified, I assume the error is in my app code, the only line of which that changed is shown above.

I then resolved the compilation error by trying the following syntax for injecting `$cookies`:

```
angular.module('auth', ['ngCookies'])
   .factory( 'auth', function($rootScope, $http, $location, $cookies) {
```

The result is that FireFox gives a diffent compilation error stating that `$cookies.get` is not a function, triggered at the following line of code:

```
authenticated1 : $cookies.get('AUTH1'),
```

To me this indicates that $cookies has not been properly inserted.

Finally, I did a key word search inside `angular-bootstrap.js` and confirmed that there are many instances of the word `cookies`, which implies that the `cookies` api is in that file in the classpath, and thus that the problem seems to be in the syntax used to insert it into the service.

**So what specific changes do I make to the code above to properly inject the `$cookies` api into the `auth` service?**

---

**ONGOING EFFORTS:**

---

As per suggestions from @charlietfl and @KenDev, I tried two changes to the syntax of the first line of the service.  Both versions cause the compilation error stating that `$cookies.get is not a function`.  To eliminate confusion, I am pasting all of the code from the actual service module as follows:

```
//angular.module('auth', ['ngCookies']).factory( 'auth', [ '$cookies', function($rootScope, $http, $location, $cookies) {
angular.module('auth', ['ngCookies']).factory('auth', ['$rootScope', '$http', '$location', '$cookies', function($rootScope, $http, $location, $cookies){
        var auth = {

            authenticated1 : $cookies.get('AUTH1'),
            authenticated2 : $cookies.get('AUTH2'),
            usrname : '',

            loginPath : '/login',
            logoutPath : '/logout',
            homePath : '/checkpin',
            path : $location.path(),

            authenticate1 : function(credentials, callback) {

                var headers = credentials && credentials.username ? {
                    authorization : "Basic " + btoa(credentials.username + ":" + credentials.password)
                } : {};

                $http.get('user', {
                    headers : headers
                }).success(function(data) {
                    if (data.name) {
                        auth.authenticated1 = $cookies.get('AUTH1');
                    } 
                    else { 
//                          $cookies.put('AUTH1', 'no');
                        auth.authenticated1 = 'no';//$cookies.get('AUTH1'); 
                    }
                    callback && callback(auth.authenticated1);
                }).error(function() {
//                      $cookies.put('AUTH1', 'no');
                    auth.authenticated1 = 'no';//$cookies.get('AUTH1');
                    callback && callback(false);
                });

            },

            authenticate2 : function(funcJSON, callback) {
                $http.post('/check-pin', funcJSON).then(function(response, $cookies) {
                    if(response.data.content=='pinsuccess'){
                        auth.authenticated2 = $cookies.get('AUTH2');
                        callback && callback(auth.authenticated2);
                    }else {
//                          $cookies.put('AUTH2', 'no');
                        auth.authenticated2 = 'no';//$cookies.get('AUTH2'); 
                        callback && callback(false);
                    }
                });
            },

            clear : function() {
                $location.path(auth.loginPath);
//                  $cookies.put('AUTH1', 'no');
                auth.authenticated1 = 'no';//$cookies.get('AUTH1'); 
//                  $cookies.put('AUTH2', 'no');
                auth.authenticated2 = 'no';//$cookies.get('AUTH2'); 

                $http.post(auth.logoutPath, {}).success(function() { console.log("Logout succeeded");
                }).error(function(data) { console.log("Logout failed"); });
            },

            init : function(homePath, loginPath, logoutPath) {

                auth.homePath = homePath;
                auth.loginPath = loginPath;
                auth.logoutPath = logoutPath;

            }
        };
        return auth;
    }]);
```

Note that I tried the above separately twice with each of the following first lines:

```
angular.module('auth', ['ngCookies']).factory( 'auth', [ '$cookies', function($rootScope, $http, $location, $cookies) {

and then separately:  

angular.module('auth', ['ngCookies']).factory('auth', ['$rootScope', '$http', '$location', '$cookies', function($rootScope, $http, $location, $cookies){
```

I then tried @gnerkis' suggestion to update the version of AngularJS.  I noticed that my `pom.xml` had version `1.3.8` of `org.webjars:angularjs`, so I looked up the latest version at maven central and changed the version to `1.4.8` in my `pom.xml`, then typed `mvn clean install -U` and `mvn clean package -U` followed by `java -jar pathto/nameofjar.jar`, but got a different compilation error saying that `angular` is not defined, and pointing to the very first word of every controller in the app.  When I then reverted the app back to `1.3.8`, I was able to re-create the @charlietfl and @KenDev error described at the start of this **ONGOING RESEARCH** section.

**What else can I try?**

As per @gnerkus' suggestion, I am posting my `index.html` as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<base href="/" />
<link href="css/angular-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], .ng-cloak {
    display: none !important;
}
</style>
</head>

<body ng-app="hello" ng-cloak class="ng-cloak">
    <div ng-controller="navigation" class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
            <li ng-class="{active:tab('home')}"><a href="/">home</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active:tab('message')}"><a href="/message">message</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active:tab('public1')}"><a href="/public1">public1</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active:tab('public2')}"><a href="/public2">public2</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active:tab('public3')}"><a href="/public3">public3</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active:tab('public4')}"><a href="/public4">public4</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active:tab('register')}"><a href="/register">register</a></li>
            <li><a href="/login">login</a></li>
            <li ng-show="authenticated2()"><a href="" ng-click="logout()">logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div ng-view class="container"></div>
    <script src="js/angular-bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/auth/auth.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/home/home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/message/message.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/public1/public1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/navigation/navigation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/hello.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: very distinct syntax difference between the way you did it for controller and for factory. Hint...there are only 2 arguments for each of `controller()` and  `factory()`

Comment: @charlietfl The `factory` code works **until** I try to inject `cookies`.  I am still learning AngularJS, and hesitate to fix something that is not broken.  But trying to inject `$cookies` broke it.

Comment: Because of missing braces...look at the differences ...controller syntax is correct...make factory syntax match. You have 3 arguments for factory() not two

Comment: @charlietfl Please see code I added to end of OP showing results of trying your suggestion.  Any other observations?

Comment: @CodeMed, In angular 1.3.x try using `var favoriteCookie = $cookies['AUTH1'];`

Comment: @KevDev `favoriteCookie : $cookies['AUTH1'],` might have resolved it.  Note the `:` and the `,`.  Your equals sign and semicolon did not work inside the `var auth { ...` declaration.

Comment: My solution wasn't intended for a JavaScript object, more for this line auth.authenticated2 = $cookies.get('AUTH2'); but you get the point. The ngCookies syntax is different in 1.3.x. If it's worked please mark my solution as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This may be a result of an older version of `angular`. In the docs for [ngCookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies), we have this line:

> Up until Angular 1.3, $cookies exposed properties that represented the current browser cookie values. In version 1.4, this behavior has changed, and $cookies now provides a standard api of getters, setters etc.

Comment: I changed the version of `org.webjars:angularjs` in the `pom.xml` to `1.4.8` instead of the previous `1.3.8`, and then typed `mvn clean install -U` and `mvn clean package -U` before restarting the app with the newly created `jar`, but the result is a different FireFox compilation error `ReferenceError: angular is not defined` at the following line of code in every controller in the app:  `angular.module('auth', ...`.  Any suggestions?

Comment: None that I can think of. I don't have a good understanding of `maven`. How are scripts loaded on the page? Could you show me a code sample?

Comment: I know how to use the firefox debugger.  Is there a way that I can extract code from that?  Or should I post `index.html`, which loads all the scripts in tags like the following: `<script src="js/angular-bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`  ?

Comment: You can post the `index.html`.

Comment: I just posted `index.html`.

Comment: I've seen it. You need to load `angular` before the `angular-bootstrap` script.

Comment: What syntax would I use to accomplish that?  I do not see a pure `angular` resource in my app.  I thought that `angular` was built into `angular-bootstrap`.

Comment: Your outside the box response helped us stumble onto the version `1.3.8` syntax, which is `variablename : $cookies['AUTH1'],`.  Note this missing `get(`, which you point out was added in version `1.4`.  Thank you and +1 for being the most thought provoking response.  Lemme think overnight about how to deal with the rest of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't injecting dependencies correctly into your services.

```
angular.module('auth', ['ngCookies']).factory( 'auth', '$cookies',  function($rootScope, $http, $location, $cookies) {}
```

Should be

```
angular.module('auth', ['ngCookies']).factory('auth', ['$rootScope', '$http', '$location', '$cookies', function($rootScope, $http, $location, $cookies){}])
```

Notice how the ordering of the dependency arguments matches the function annotations provided as strings. Also notice the brackets.

See this page on the angular docs paying special attention to the [Note on Minification](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#a-note-on-minification)

Edit,
In angular 1.3.x use this syntax for getting and setting cookies

```
 var storedCookie = $cookies['key']; // get
 $cookies['key'] = 'something'; // set
```

Comment: Please see code I added to the end of my OP showing results of your suggestions.

Comment: Thank you.  The snippet I added in a comment to the OP got things to proceed without the compilation errors.  I need to think on this overnight.  It is late here now where I am.